# Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc Getting Default Adapter failed

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to learn how to use selenium and python , I want to crawl the news title & news date of this [website](https://www.thestandnews.com/search/?q=%E6%96%B0%E5%86%A0%E8%82%BA%E7%82%8E)
but I have a problem that I don't know how to solve.

This is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd  
import time
import json
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.thestandnews.com/search/?q=%E6%96%B0%E5%86%A0%E8%82%BA%E7%82%8E")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
pages_remaining = True
page_num = 1

My_array = []
while pages_remaining:
 print("Page Number:", page_num)

 soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
""" #undoned

 tags_lis = soup.find_all("li")
 for tag in tags_lis:
    tag_a = tag.find("a")
    tag_span = tag.find("span")
    title = tag_a.text
    date = tag_span.text
    temp = {"title": title , "date": date}
    print(temp)
    My_array.append(temp)
   """
  try:
    #Press button of next page
    #next_link =driver.find_element_by_xpath()
    nextPg = '//*[@id="___gcse_1"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[%d]' % (page_num + 1)
    print(nextPg)
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(nextPg)
    next_link.click()

    time.sleep(5)
    if page_num < 10:
        page_num = page_num + 1
    else:
        pages_remaining = False
  except Exception:
    pages_remaining = False 
driver.close()
```

and this is the error message, can anyone give a hint ,thanks!

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49952/devtools/browser/749fcb19-d13a-4f38-9d7c-3da58726e10a
[13744:13732:0517/214816.873:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
Page Number: 1
//*[@id="___gcse_1"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]
[13744:13732:0517/214824.321:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(162)] [21:48:24.321] Bluetooth: 
bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1055 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Page Number: 2
//*[@id="___gcse_1"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]
```

Comment: I have similar problem, did you find any solution? -- 
my problem  --- 
Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:713 GetBluetoothAdapterStaticsActivationFactory failed: Class not registered (0x80040154)

Comment: I used firefox instead

Comment: have you tried another browser or so? or webdriver-manager package what install chromedriver automatically?

Comment: It's late, but the answer is here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507597/11863448]

Comment: @Vincent - Upvote if you think it helps you and others.