# Bluetooth adapter error messages regarding Registry Keys and Experimental Options

Tags: python, selenium

I'm getting this error when I try to run my selenium test:

`[9680:18428:0605/111414.227:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:14:14.228] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.`

```
This is how my `conftest.py` file looks like:
```

**Code**

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
Facebook = "https://facebook.com"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=60)

@pytest.fixture
def set_up():
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(Facebook)
```

As you can see I'm trying to make tests for Facebook using Google Chrome, but for some reason I get the mentioned error, does anyone know how to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Suppress this error by using below.

As per the documentation in [Selenium Chrome Driver: Resolve Error Messages Regarding Registry Keys and Experimental Options](http://blogs.stevelongchen.com/2020/05/15/selenium-chrome-driver-resolve-error-messages-regarding-registry-keys-and-experimental-options/) these error logs can be supressed by adding the argument:

```
excludeSwitches: ['enable-logging']
```

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```